# Proving $\sqrt{x}$ is not a rational function

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field, rational-functions

I've got a monster of a proof by contradiction going where to finish I need to show that there is no $\alpha\in \mathbb{Q}(x)$ (the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$) such that $\alpha^2=x$. Obviously this is equivalent to showing that $\sqrt{x}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(x)$, which seems trivial enough, but I'm stuck.

Here's what I've done so far:

If $\sqrt{x}=\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$ where $q(x)=a_0+...+a_nx^n$, then $p(x)=a_0x^{1/2}+...+a_nx^{n/2}$. It seems like this is a contradiction, but we are of course not prevented from choosing $a_0,...,a_n$ to be nonzero only for even terms greater than two, so it isn't.

Is there a quick algebraic proof of this fact?

Comment: Hint:  try to adapt the proof that $\sqrt 2\not \in \mathbb Q$.  Start with $xq^2(x)=p^2(x)$.

Comment: rational function where the polynomials are real?

Comment: More simply, one could just note that, if you had suitable $p,q$, then $\sqrt 2 =\frac {p(2)}{q(2)}\in \mathbb Q$.

Comment: You can prove by using the algebraic properties that a rational function whose square is $x$ must satisfy, or by looking at the growth rates of rational functions.

Comment: Assuming it is, you can also get a contradiction about the degrees of the polynomials.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$
\text{------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
$$
Suppose there exists $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}(x)$ such that $|\alpha(x)|=\sqrt{x}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $x\ge 0$.

Then in particular, we have $|\alpha(2)|=\sqrt{2}$, contradiction, since $\alpha(2)$ can't be irrational.
$$
\text{------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
$$
Here's another way . . .

Suppose there exists $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}(x)$ such that $\alpha^2=x$.

Then in particular, we have $\bigl(\alpha(-1)\bigr)^2=-1$, contradiction, since $\bigl(\alpha(-1)\bigr)^2$ can't be negative.
$$
\text{------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
$$
Here's still another way, which has the advantage of working for $K(x)$, where $K$ is any field . . .

Let $K$ be a field, and suppose there exists $\alpha\in K(x)$ such that $\alpha^2=x$.

Then writing $\alpha={\large{\frac{p}{q}}}$ for some nonzero $p,q\in K[x]$, we get
$$
p^2=xq^2
$$
contradiction, since $\deg(p^2)$ is even, whereas $\deg(xq^2)$ is odd.
$$
\text{------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
$$

Answer (score 5):

If $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are polynomials, let $m=\deg p(x)$ and let $n=\deg q(x)$. Then$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt x}{p(x)/q(x)}=\begin{cases}\infty&\text{ if }m-n\leqslant0\\0&\text{ if }m-n>0.\end{cases}$$Therefore, $\sqrt x$ is not a rational function; if it was equal to $\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}$, that limit would be $1$.

Comment: Can you answer my little question? Is my claim correct?  If $\text{deg}~f(x)>\text{deg}~g(x)$, then  
 $\text{deg}~f'(x)>\text{deg}~g'(x)$. Thank you!

Comment: @lonestudent Yes, for non-constant polynomials.