# Alternative proofs that square root is irrational function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, proof-writing, solution-verification, rational-functions

My work is to show alternative proof that $\sqrt x$ is irrational function.

The simplest proof might be to find a "counter-example".  I mean, it is enough to show that $\sqrt 2=\dfrac{f(2)}{g(2)}$ is irrational.

I found the [argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4090337/460967) based on this argument I said in M.SE.

> Suppose there exists $\alpha\in\mathbb{Q}(x)$ such that $|\alpha(x)|=\sqrt{x}$ for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ with $x\ge 0$.
>
> Then in particular, we have $|\alpha(2)|=\sqrt{2}$, contradiction, since $\alpha(2)$ can't be irrational.

---

The argument that one of the functions $f^2(x)$ and $xg^2(x)$ has a even degree and the other has a odd degree is also valid.

---

Now I want to know whether these two proofs that I have made are valid too.

Let, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be polynomials, such that

$$\sqrt x=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \Longrightarrow x=\frac{f^2(x)}{g^2(x)}$$

Then,

$$\deg \left (f^2(x)-g^2(x)\right)=\deg x=1$$

$$2 \deg \left (f(x)-g(x)\right)=1$$

$$\deg \left (f(x)-g(x)\right)=\frac 12 \not\in\mathbb Z^{+}$$

Thus, we can deduce such $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ doesn't exist.

---

By accepting

$$\sqrt x=\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$

$$\deg f(x)=m ~~\text{and}~~ \deg g(x)=n, $$

$$m,n\in\mathbb Z^{+}∪\left\{0\right\}$$

Then,

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\infty \implies m-n≥1$$

Then let $x≠0$, we have

$$\frac{\sqrt x}{x}=\frac{f(x)}{xg(x)}$$

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt x}=\frac{f(x)}{xg(x)}$$

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x)}{xg(x)}=0 \implies n+1-m≥1$$

Finally we have,

$$\begin{cases} m-n≥1\\ n+1-m≥1 \end{cases} \implies \begin{cases} m-n≥1 \\m-n≤0\end{cases} $$

$$\implies \left\{m,n\right\}\in \emptyset.$$

---

Are there any points / steps I missed?

Which proofs / arguments are valid and which are not?

<sub>Thank you.</sub>

Comment: That $\frac{f(2)}{g(2)}$ is irrational does not refute that $\sqrt{x}$ is a rational function since $f$ and $g$ need not have rational coefficients.

Comment: @Peter Thank you for comment! I was surprised why this hasn't occurred to me before.  But this answer seems to be valid.  Probably, I could not get the answer right in my question...
    https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4090337/460967

Comment: The approach with the degrees is interesting and I think also valid. I just tried to find an easier alternative.

Comment: Ah, I just realize that the degree-approach gives an even easier argument. The degrees of $f^2(x)$ and $g^2(x)$ are both even , hence $x\cdot g^2(x)$ has odd degree hence $x\cdot g^2(x)$ and $f^2(x)$ cannot coincide. This is very elegant indeed !

Comment: @Peter So the argument $\sqrt 2$ is disabled. But "degree argument" is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**solution-verification**

I think that the first proof that you have made is not valid.

I think that there is an error in the following step :

> $\deg \left (f^2(x)-g^2(x)\right)=\deg x=1$
> $2 \deg \left (f(x)-g(x)\right)=1$

It is not always true that
$$\deg \left (f^2(x)-g^2(x)\right)=2 \deg \left (f(x)-g(x)\right)$$

For example, if $f(x)=x+1$ and $g(x)=x$, then we have
$$\deg \left (f^2(x)-g^2(x)\right)=1\not= 0=2\deg \left (f(x)-g(x)\right)$$

---

I think that the second proof that you have made is valid.

---

**Added** :

Regarding the argument you found: I found no error, so I think that it is valid.

Comment: Would you like to add details to your answer regarding the argument I found in MS.E?  Thank you for checking the my attempts.

Comment: @lone student : I've checked the argument you found.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm confused. Why did Peter said that this argument is not valid?(and gave me a valid counter-example)  Or am I missing something??

Comment: @lone student : Because Peter thought that $f(x),g(x)$ are polynomials with **real** coefficients. The [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4090320/proving-sqrtx-is-not-a-rational-function) says that "$\alpha\in \mathbb{Q}(x)$ (the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Q}[x]$)". This means that $\alpha(x)$ has to be of the form $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials with **rational** coefficients. So, the argument you found is valid.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! My goal was to prove that $\sqrt x$ is not rational function. In this context we can say that this argument is weak, because doesn't cover all cases. am I right? (works only with rational coefficients) . So, finally I have $2$ valid proof , "degree argument" and "second proof" do I think right, mathlove?

Comment: @lone student : Yes, you are right.

Comment: No need to edit your answer.  You explained in detail in your comment. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What abouth this proof : I start with $$x\cdot g^2(x)=f^2(x)$$ for some polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

We can assume that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are not both divisible by $x$, otherwise we can divide both $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ by $x$ until we have the desired representation.

On the other hand, we have $f(0)=0$ , hence $f(x)$ must be disivible by $x$.

Since $f^2(x)$ is divisible by $x^2$, we have that $g^2(x)$ is divisible by $x$ which implies that $g(x)$ is divisible by $x$.

This is the desired contradiction.

Comment: (+1)Thank you @Peter. Would you like to explain the argument $\sqrt 2$ .. I got the answer from the site.  But I probably got it wrong.

Comment: Suppose , $f(x)=x-2+\sqrt{2}$ and $g(x)=x-1$. Then, $\frac{f(2)}{g(2)}=\sqrt{2}$